# Open Source macOS Uninstaller

Tags: open-source, osx, macos, uninstall

Is there a reliable, free/open source macOS uninstaller application?

I want to remove things like GarageBand, iMovies and other Apple & non-Apple software.

Moving these things to the trash can will leave other folders untouched, like `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand/`, so I wanted something that could do a proper cleanup automagically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an app called app cleaner that will uninstall completely any app you choose. It can be downloaded from [here.](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)

Comment: Somehow I missed this notification and only saw your answer now. I tried it, AppCleaner seems perfect, thank you!